# display: unable to open X server

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-yosemite, display

I am running ImageMagick on my Mac which runs on Yosemite. I have just downloaded ImageMagick and I am trying to open the logo display by running this on the command line:

```
display logo.gif
```

after executing the above command, I am getting the following error:

```
display: unable to open X server `:0.0' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
```

I've implemented all the steps to install ImageMagick, including executing the following command:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and I am still not getting the display to show up. When I echo $DISPLAY, my console shows 0.0.

How can I fix this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is [X server](http://www.xquartz.org) running?

Comment: OSX no longer includes X11 (X Windows). As Eric says, you would need to install XQuartz if you want to use Image!agick's `display` program. Else you could click on an image to select it in the Finder and tap the spacebar to get a Quicklook preview of an image. Or, if in the Terminal, you can type `open logo.gif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not attempt to export the `$DISPLAY` environment variable, as this will be set when X11 (XQuartz) is launched. On OS X, this is usually a unique unix path. Something like:

```sh
 echo $DISPLAY
 #=> /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.CWOgR6ULcX/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

The best way to start X sever (IMHO) is to use [Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(software))

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
2. Search for "`X11`" followed by <kbd>↩</kbd>
3. Open new terminal window & run your `display` command

Comment: why was this downvoted? Also I've never had to manually start Xquartz on macOS, after installing its just always been available, maybe it auto-starts on login?