# running xvfb-run on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, xvfb

Is it possible to get xvfb-run to work in the newest version of OS X? I've installed XQuartz and Xvfb runs the scripts with the following command:

```
Xvfb :4000 & export DISPLAY=:4000 & rspec
```

instead of this one:

```
xvfb-run rspec
```

This is however not without fault, either the temp file "x4000-lock" will not get removed after the script is finished and stop Xvfb to start up again or I'll recieve this error next time the script runs:

> [2] 13220
>   [3] 13221
>   _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
>   _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
>   (EE) 
>   Fatal server error:
>   (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
>   Run options: include {:focus=>true}

This error is also recieved on a linux system so i Suspect "xvfb-run" is doing something more in the background and thus wondering how to get that running in OS X

Comment: This may be relevant... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36252272/2836621

Comment: as per comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32786365/5359531), `xvfb-run` is just a shell script so you can open it and see exactly what it is doing.